# Getting rails feedback plugin to work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, actionmailer, mailchimp

I am using the simple rails gem feedback_popup and I have followed all the instructions. It works fine locally but when I push to heroku it no longer sends the email with the feedback though the logs look like it should:

```
Started POST "/feedback_popup/messages" for 89.27.92.12 at 2013-08-30 08:59:05 +0000
2013-08-30T08:59:05.904701+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-30T08:59:06.008570+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to info@example.com (110ms)
2013-08-30T08:59:06.109094+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by FeedbackPopup::MessagesController#create as JS
2013-08-30T08:59:06.209392+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2jo/keno5XMWc1IgnyJUPBAu5vpLi4uzpHIRQrP+HeA=", "feedback_popup_message"=>{"body"=>"why doesn't this work"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
2013-08-30T08:59:06.310876+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/feedback_popup-0.0.1/app/views/feedback_popup/mailer/feedback.text.erb (0.0ms)
2013-08-30T08:59:06.412572+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/feedback_popup-0.0.1/app/views/feedback_popup/messages/create.js.erb (0.1ms)
2013-08-30T08:59:06.513491+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 118ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-08-30T08:59:05.899365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/feedback_popup/messages host=www.baybel.com fwd="89.27.92.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=132ms status=200 bytes=70
```

I am using MailChimp and that does a perfect job of sending the welcome email when people sign up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It now works and I can think of two reasons:

1) Heroku didn't like that the config.mail_from was not an email address previously.
2) There were issues precompiling the assets.